# stop ë getting transformed to Ã« in Angular2

Tags: angular, utf-8, encode

I am running into an issue where a string is getting transformed to some other string. Something like this -> "geïnkt" is getting transformed to this "geÃ¯nkt". Inside my template I have an object tag like this:
`<object type="text/html" [data]="file"></object>`

and inside my component:

``` const elem = document.createElement("textarea");
    elem.innerHTML = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.NONE, this.content);
    let url = ``data:text/html,${this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.NONE, elem.value.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />'))}``;
    this.file = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url); ```

So, some sanitization I am doing. Now the thing is when I inspect the element, I can see the data properly getting passed to the data property. But once I open up the object div a bit further, I have structure like this:
`#document -> <html><head></head><body><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">geÃ¯nkt</div></body></html>`

I tried giving charset:UTF-8 but that also didn`t help. Can anybody help me understand what is going on in here?

Comment: you need to create a plunkr that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, seems like the encoding was an issue when I was trying to form the url after sanitization. What I did:

``` let url = ``data:text/html;charset=utf-8,${this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.NONE, elem.value.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />'))} ```;

included the charset encoding as well and it is working.